# HTML + values out of two text forms

Tags: html, forms, developer-tools, otrs

I need a way to get the values out of two text forms/fields and put them together in one hidden textbox.

e.g.
Password 1: water
Password 2: 12561

The hidden password-form should now contain "water12561"

Why do I need this?
I have a OTRS-Login with OTP(one time password) and want to authenticate the user with the OTP and the password which is stored in the mysql-DB/LDAP. The normal way is, that the user has to type in both values in one filed but this isn't a good way in my opinion. Because of this reason I want to create two field and set the password together in one field to submit this to the perl-script.

btw - there is no PHP installed on the machine.

Comment: Why don't you send both fields to the perl-script and combine them there?

Comment: Can you use Javascript? This would be trivial with any modern JS library, like jQuery for instance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with perl - maybe you'll have an idea? Auth-Module: https://github.com/privacyidea/privacyidea/blob/master/authmodules/OTRS/privacyIDEA-4_0.pm

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snippet that works via JavaScript.  I made the password field visible so you can see it working.  You'll simply need to make the password field hidden to meet your requirements.

```js
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    concatFields();
});

function concatFields()
{
  var val1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var val2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  var password = val1 + val2;

  document.getElementById("password").value = password;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>input 1</label>
  <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="add value here">
</div>
<div>
  <label>input 2</label>
  <input id="input2" type="text" placeholder="add value here">
</div>
<div>
  <label>password</label>
  <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="do not add value here">
</div>
<div>
  <input id="button" type="button" value="Concat field 1 and 2, then insert into field 3">
</div>
```